# Python SimpleHTTPServer Change Service Directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, simplehttpserver

I wrote the following piece of code to start an HTTP server, with a future option of being able to start a TCP/IP server instead:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import time
import socket

def choose():
if raw_input("Would you like to start an HTTP or TCP/IP Server?: ") == "HTTP":
    print "You have selected HTTP server."
    if raw_input("Is this correct? Use Y/N to answer. ") == "Y":
        print ""
        start_HTTP()
    else:
        choose()
else:
    print "Goodbye! "

def start_HTTP():
    PORT = int(raw_input("Which port do you want to send out of? "))
    Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
    print "Please wait one moment..."
    time.sleep(2)
    run_HTTP(PORT, httpd)

def run_HTTP(PORT, httpd):
    print "Use the following IP address to connect to this server (LAN only): " + [(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 80)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1] #prints local IP address
    print "Now serving from port: ", PORT
    print "To shutdown the server, use the PiServer_Off software."
    time.sleep(2)
    print ""
    print "Any traffic through the server will be recorded and displayed below: "
    httpd.serve_forever()

choose()
```

I want to change the directory so that at a future point, no one but the host machine can terminate the server (since the PiServer Off software will be installed in the same directory).

I found this solution, but it looks to be for a shell, and I do not know how to modify it for my code (using Pycharm): http://www.tecmint.com/python-simplehttpserver-to-create-webserver-or-serve-files-instantly/

```
# pushd /x01/tecmint/; python –m SimpleHTTPServer 9999; popd;
```

I also found this but it does not seem to answer my question: [Change directory Python SimpleHTTPServer uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414732/change-directory-python-simplehttpserver-uses)

I was wondering if anyone could share and explain their way of changing the directory without moving the server file, as I want to use this to build an in-home file-sharing system.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `os.chdir` then follow as you normally would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.chdir` to change the current directory then follow as you normally would to start the server.

Answer (score 2):

The question [How to run a http server which serves a specific path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52531444/2628864) is basically a duplicate of this one.
However, the solution proposed by [Andy Hayden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240268/andy-hayden) over there seems more appropriate.
(It's less 'hacky'/ dependent on side effects, and uses the class constructor instead.)

Goes like this:

```python
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000
DIRECTORY = "web"


class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=DIRECTORY, **kwargs)


with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

The code above works for Python >= 3.6
For Python up to 3.5, there was no contextmanager protocol available for TCPServer's base class, but that just means you need to change the `with` statement and turning it into a plain assignment:

```
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
```

Credits to [Anthony Sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile) for this [last detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396575/cannot-run-python3-httpserver-on-arm-processor).

Comment: The directory option doesn't seem to be on [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.directory) document. It shows on [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.directory) onward.